# Do I need to Block_copy a block that I pass to NSOperation's setCompletionBlock:?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation

I have a NSOperation's subclass and I want to do something like this:

```
@interface MyOperation : NSOperation...

MyOperation *myOperation = [[MyOperation alloc] init];

[myOperation setCompletionBlock = [^{
    [myOperation doSomething]; // Do something with myOperation and other classes captured from original environment

    [myOperation setCompletionBlock:nil]; // Manually setting to nil avoid retain cycles;
} copy]; <- is this "copy" needed here?
```

And so my question for this code is the title question:

**Do I need to copy (Block_copy()) the block I pass to setCompletionBlock: or NSOperation will do it for me?**

Comment: Nope.  NSOperation needs to block copy it away from you because of how atomic operations are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [-[NSOperation setCompletionBlock:] reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW36):

> The block to be executed when the operation finishes. This method creates a copy of the specified block. The block itself should take no parameters and have no return value.

So no, you don't need to copy the block as NSOperation already does this for you.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb on this, somehow I overlooked exactly the head line with these words. Thanks for the quick reaction.

Answer (score 2):

Any API that explicitly takes a block type parameter must already take care of whether to copy it or not.

Only when you pass a block to an API that takes a generic object pointer type argument do you ever need to worry about whether to copy it.